# How to structure a Microservice solution

Tags: c#, architecture, microservices

When I'm thinking about creating a Microservice solution.

Should I create a different project for my Domain? Maybe my question should be if I must share common projects between different solutions.

The benefit of it will be other Microservice could share this Domain project.

This is often my approach to a monolithic project. I normally create a project for Domain where I add Models and DTOs. Also, I have a project for some common classes.

This is my first Microservice solution and I'm not sure about how to approach it, I already had a look on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909182/microservice-solution-structure-in-net-applications). But I'm not convinced yet.

Comment: There is a lot to writing microservices, at least to writing _good_ microservices. And I found out the hard way that it's better to have a monolith than _bad_ microservices. I think the topic is way to broad to fit this programming Q&A format, but if you want to read a bit more, maybe [this article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) is a good starting point. The article itself has a reading list as well. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is very general,  but I can share a couple of thoughts.

1. 9/10 cases,  would not require sharing dtos and models or dals. This is because microservices are meant to be independent of each other, with their own models and databases.
2. For horizontal aspects, maybe you will need them,  but it's better to use other providers to do your logging, notifications and such
3. Yes, some contacts could be shareable in the nuget or any other packaging format, when one domain model adheres fully to another domain and they are communicating with each other.

As a general rule, if you need a microservices architecture, try to go the full way. Learn about domain driven design, learn about the advantages of said structure and let them be an option even if you don't use them.

Remember, microservices are meant to be written by individual teams, possibly using different technologies and programming frameworks.